# In fstream, why read() and write() require const char*?

Tags: c++, binary, fstream

I trying to write a C++ program that can make a copy of a bmp file:

```
unsigned char* BMP_in(const char* filename) {
    ifstream f(filename, ios::binary);
    if (!f.is_open())
        return NULL;

    f.seekg(0, ios::end); //put pointer to the end of file
    int size = f.tellg();
    f.seekg(0, ios::beg);

    unsigned char* data = new unsigned char[size];

    f.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data), size);
    //why I can't just f.read(data,size)?

    return data;
}
```

In these line:

```
unsigned char* data = new unsigned char[size];

f.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data), size);
```

I had to cast data to char* to avoid error. This is not the only case that we need to cast that thing. So I wonder why we need to do that? Why read() and write() dont just take any type of pointer?

Comment: What `const`? `fread()` does not require `const`. Otherwise it couldn't read any data into your buffer.

Comment: `char` and `unsigned char`, while related, are totally different types in C++.  It won't let you mix them unless you tell the compiler "hey I know what I'm doing".  And if you're wrong then the fault is yours.

Comment: @user207421 Im asking about read() and write() in ifstream

Comment: @MarkRansom Ransom yeah Your right. I found this code in another question, they use fread. I covert them to * read().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `std::ifstream` is [`std::basic_ifstream<char>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream).

If you wish to read unsigned chars, use

```
std::basic_ifstream<unsigned char> f(filename, ios::binary);
```